# How to enable KVM in RHEL running on a VM?

Tags: redhat, kvm-virtualization

I need to run android emulators in a RHEL 7 virtual machine however it says that my machine should have KVM support. When I ran the lscpu command, the Virtualization type returns full. Does this mean that I cannot enable KVM and thus not able to run android emulators in this machine?

Thanks in advance for all your answers.

Comment: Check with this command (for Intel CPU): cat /sys/module/kvm_intel/parameters/nested

Comment: @batistuta09 the directory kvm_intel is not present in module.

Comment: and what about kvm_amd (or smth similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify cpu compatibility:

cat /proc/cpuinfo

and verify if vmx or svm is present.

If not, you cannot have KVM.

If yes, try install virtualization at first:

yum groupinstall "Virtualization Host"

And then start and enable libvirtd with: systemctl enable libvirtd ; systemctl start libvirtd

If you are on a VirtualBox VM, it is not supported.

Comment: lsmod | grep kvm should return loaded kernel modules.

Comment: @Giorgio Binazzi, thank you for your reply. i can't find vmx or svm in anywhere in the output of cat /proc/cpuinfo so this means that my cpu doesn't support nested virtualization and in turn i can't install kvm right?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much.